# Q: Facebook AR Studio - Array of scene objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, augmented-reality

I am trying to have an array of Scene objects but only returns null

```js
function findMasks() {
    let x = 7;
    var maskList = [];
    for (i = 1; i < x; i++) {
        var mask = Scene.root.find('mask' + i)
        maskList.push(mask)
    }
    return maskList
}
var maskList = findMasks();
Diagnostics.log(maskList);
```

Is that possible in AR Studio?

Answer (score 0):

This should work, I've done something similar to this in the past myself. Your code looks correct, so my guess is that there might be a discrepancy with the way the objects are named in AR Studio.